# error and problems after upgrading quasar

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vuejs3, quasar

fellow devs,
I have a quasar project that I have recently (stupidly) upgraded to the latest version to test it with vue 3. unfortunately my app does not launch and I get the following

> (node:7976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:   TypeError: Merging undefined is not supported

> - index.js:63 mergeWithOptions
>   [StayFit]/[webpack-merge]/dist/index.js:63:19

> - index.js:52 merge
>   [StayFit]/[webpack-merge]/dist/index.js:52:35

> - quasar-conf-file.js:392 QuasarConfFile.compile
>   [StayFit]/[@quasar]/app/lib/quasar-conf-file.js:392:29

> - task_queues.js:95 processTicksAndRejections
>   internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5

> - quasar-dev:237 async goLive
>   [StayFit]/[@quasar]/app/bin/quasar-dev:237:3

> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> (node:7976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:7976) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I have tried to roll back quasar version or uninstall it and reinstall a certain version but still the same issue.

any solution there?

Comment: rollback your commit and wait until Quasar V2 stops using beta versions of dependent packages.

Comment: Stupid lazy me didn't use version control, and when quasar is going to stop using the beta versions?